# SQL/relational algebra and date != string error

Tags: relational-algebra

Trying to display names and dates of Iowa ships that have had least one battle in the year 1943 or later. However, every time I go to use date under the Battles table I can not compare it to a date ('YYYY-DD-MM').

This is what it keeps showing

[image: This is what it keeps showing]

Comment: I'm executing it with https://dbis-uibk.github.io/relax/calc.htm# . It is a relational algebra calculator my teacher assigned us. The database is under the Database Systems The Complete Book - Exercise 2.4.3 tab on the left side.

Comment: Don't know about this calculator, but in Standard SQL it's `DATE '1943-01-01'`

Comment: Why do you have SQL in the title?

Comment: For future reference, please type/copy text into your question rather than only having an image. (You can google 'unicode pi' for special characters.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had to cast your string representation of  date as actual date data type:
    `(π name σ class = 'Iowa' (Ships)) ⨝ (π date σ date > date('1943-01-01') (Battles))`

Comment: Thank you! It worked, and thank you for understanding what I was doing.